# CSS Background image problems

Tags: html, css

Hi been trying to get this for quite some time. Ive done it before which is why i feel pretty pathetic for having to ask. The background will not show up.

Im trying to set a background image for my footer and the top menu on my website located  [HERE](http://sadin.me/)

This is my CSS for the Footer:

```
.blog-footer {
   padding: 40px 0;
   color: #999;
   text-align: center;
   background-image: url('./classy_fabric/classy_fabic.png');
   border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

And here is the CSS for the top nav:

```
.blog-masthead {
   background-image: url('./classy_fabric/classy_fabic.png');
   box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

Comment: And the problem you're having is...?

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: My bad forgot to add that for some reason... The background image is not showing up.

Comment: check image url... most likely it is the reason

Comment: Please do **not** link to your site! When your site changes, the issue is fixed, goes offline, is dead, etc.. the link will become completely useless to future users with similar issues. In fact it looks like this question is now redundant as the issue cannot be reproduced and the answer will make no sense to future users either. In general when asking a question, include **all** relevant code , including the relevant HTML, in the question directly and in addition, if needed, create an isolated demo using [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) (or similar) to demonstrate the issue at hand.

Answer (score 2):

You have fabric mispelled so it can't find it.

http://sadin.me/css/classy_fabric/classy_fabric.png

Comment: Ah shoot thanks. I must be blind.

Answer (score 1):

I found one glitch in you code.

`background-image: url('./classy_fabric/classy_fabic.png'); one` (`.`) is missing

```
background-image: url('../classy_fabric/classy_fabic.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to move your file into the right directory.

```
Request URL:http://sadin.me/css/classy_fabric/classy_fabic.png
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

If you're using Chrome, check out the network tab of your debug console for any 404 errors.